# Make url from string - sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have string **gitproject**

How can I use sed command with *gitproject argument* in order to do:

- `http://user_name:user_password@example.com/gitproject.git`
- `http://example.com/gitproject.git`

BR

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`${VARIABLE_NAME}` syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to expand a shell variable without adding any extra whitespace on either side, e.g.:

```
proj=gitproject
echo http://user_name_userpassword@example.com/${proj}.git
echo http://example.com/${proj}.git
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for sed:

```
str="gitproject"
echo "http://user_name:user_password@example.com/${str}.git"
echo "http://example.com/${str}.git"
```